# Winpcap 3.1 install error on windows95

Tags: installation, winpcap, windows-95

I'm trying to install winpcap 3.1 (stable) on a windows95 vm (vmware).
I get an install error with the following message:
What to do? My aim is to install windump or ethereal ...
[image]

I have googled NSWEB.DLL => nothing.

Whens I run windump I get (after a few seconds) some hex dump then a long spill of 0000 then a crash (all of this happening in a command terminal).
My idea is that the problem comes from the instruction set of the cpu configured in my vmware client. But I'm not sure about this at all...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run a tool like that on a virtual machine because there is no physical ethernet card - just an emulated one.

I think the emulated card is very different from the real one because the virtual machine is to support bridged networking to the physical one on the machine, as well as other connection modes such as shared, static and whatnot (I don't recall the proper terms for these connections).